# Windows 10 Multi Monitor support issues

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport

First, the setup:

I have two monitors at my work station:

1. 24" Dell P2414
2. 34" LG 34UM95C-P

...plugged into an AMD FirePro W2100 (FireGL V).

(1) is DisplayPort to DVI adapter, (2) is plugged via DisplayPort. All drivers are up to date on both monitors and video card.

Now the problem:

Whenever I lock my computer and leave it for 5-10 minutes, I come back to find that the non-primary monitor (2) is seemingly disconnected and reconnected from the computer, and all open windows/applications screens are gathered into the primary monitor (1). To be specific: I log back onto the computer, both monitors properly display desktops, but primary monitor (1) has all of my windows and applications gathered onto it so I have to reorganize and move my programs around again.

Has anyone experienced this recurring issue with Windows 10 and multi-monitors? I have had other problems with this mutli-monitor setup which makes me think Windows 10 just sucks in this regard, but I'd like to address the reproducible errors first.

I have a laptop which I plug into a similar LG monitor via USB-C, which has the exact same issue when I lock and leave for 5-10 minutes so it doesn't seem to be isolated to this computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the power settings to prevent this from happening:

`Power Options > Turn off the display > Never`

After looking into enabling GPU scaling on the AMD drivers, I also noticed that I had a nVidia drivers installed from a previous video card (big whoops). Uninstalled all nVidia drivers and applications, seems to be more stable now. Haven't had an app-regrouping since making these two changes.